# Evento MySQL que inserte datos en una tabla según cantidad de registros de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Buen día.

Necesito crear un evento en `MySQL` que se ejecute el primer día de cada mes e inserte registros en una tabla, según la cantidad de registros obtenido de otra tabla.

He intentado con esta estructura:

```
CREATE EVENT statistics
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
    DO
        SELECT * FROM `tabla_lectura`
        FOR EACH ROW
            SET @title = (SELECT `title` FROM `tabla_lectura`)
            SET @hits = (SELECT `hits` FROM `tabla_lectura`)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO `tabla_escritura` (title, hits) VALUES (@title,@hits)
            END
        END FOR
```

Pero obtengo este error:

> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'EACH ROW
>               SET @title = (SELECT `title` FROM `tabla_lectura`)
>      ' en la linea 5

La idea es que por cada registro de la `tabla_lectura`, inserte esos dos valores en `tabla_escritura`

Cuál es la estructura correcta para lograrlo?

La verdad, es la primera vez que intento crear eventos y no estoy muy familiarizado con la sintaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunos comentarios:

- La documentación referenciada estará en inglés.
- La sección [13.1.13 CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) de la documentación es un buen punto de inicio.
- `FOR EACH ROW` aplica realmente a disparadores (triggers), ver [24.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Una posible opción para lograr lo que necesita es la siguiente:

```sql
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `statistics`;

CREATE EVENT `statistics` ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS '2019-01-01 00:00:01'
DO
  INSERT INTO `tabla_escritura` (`title`, `hits`)
  SELECT `title`, `hits`
  FROM `tabla_lectura`;
```

No estoy seguro si debe consultar toda la tabla `tabla_lectura` cada mes cuando se ejecute el evento (EVENT), pero puede hacer todas las modificaciones que sean necesarias.

Comment: Funciona perfecto!